# Cakephp: Routing and default views

Tags: cakephp

I'm currently trying to add an admin mode to my cakephp site.

I followed a tutorial on the web and added a routing prefix:

```
Configure::write('Routing.prefixes', array('admin'));
```

Then I implemented login and logout functionality.

I added a admin_view.ctp and admin_index.ctp to a model where I want to restrict access. Therefore I deleted view.ctp and index.ctp and expected that only admins could view the model by using:

```
http://xxxx/model/admin/index
```

But when I entered

```
http://xxxx/model/index
```

a default view appeared that I could not disable (it allows model manipulation). Is there a standard way to disable all these default views or do I have to create a index.ctp and view.ctp that simply show error messages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to disallow certain action, you need to setup ACL, which is described [here](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1242/Access-Control-Lists). And for authentication, in your controller you need something like this:

```
class SomethingsController extends AppController
{
var $components = array('Auth');

//this will allow all users access to the index
//and view methods ( but not any other)
    function beforeFilter() {
            $this->Auth->allow('index','view');
    }

// other actions
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Delete default controller methods: `function index(), view(), add(), edit() and delete()`. Removing *.ctp templates is not enough.

Comment: they are all gone... yet cakephp creates a default view

Comment: I just noticed that when I create a function index(){} that is empty in addition to function admin_index(){...} the default view is not shown by cakephp but it complains that I haven't created the index.ctp.

Comment: probably you have "scaffolding" enabled. Delete $scaffold variable in all controllers.